# Store and retrieve strings in ArrayAdapter with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer

I need to save and retrieve two strings in an `ArrayAdapter` of my `NavigationDrawer`.
First of all. I declared this:

```
private static SharedPreferences prefs;
```

then in the getView() method

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("username", NameStr);
        editor.putString("photo", urlProfile);
        editor.commit();
```

In this way i'm going to save the strings i need. But i'm not exactly sure because i never use the Sharedpreferences in an Adapter. How can i retrieve the datas? Where have i to put it? thanks

EDIT:
to achieve the strings i wrote in getView()

```
Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
            NameStr = intent.getStringExtra("username");
            urlProfile = intent.getStringExtra("photo");
```

where the two strings comes from another activity.

EDIT2: SOLUTION
Dexter got the solution and it works perfectly:

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS",context. MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedPreferences == null) return;        
        NameStr = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
        urlProfile = sharedPreferences.getString("photo", "");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();        
        Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
        if(NameStr == null || NameStr.equals("")) {
            NameStr = intent.getStringExtra("username");
            editor.putString("username", NameStr);
        }
        if(urlProfile == null || urlProfile.equals("")) {
            urlProfile = intent.getStringExtra("photo");
            editor.putString("photo", urlProfile);
        }
        editor.apply();
```

all of this in the Adapter construction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the data using :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
String photo = sharedPreferences.getString("photo", "");
```

Also prefer using editor.apply()

Comment: Where have i to write it? Is it correct save the datas in the getView() method as i done? And your code to retrieve goes where? remember that is a class that extends an ArrayAdapter

Comment: See, SharedPreferences is global disk space provided to your application. You can access it from anywhere, you just need a non null context object. I’m not sure what you a re trying to achieve, but if you put your code in a getView, it will lead to a lot of overwrites over the keys, username and photo. The code to retrieve can go anywhere you want it. You just need a non null context object.

Comment: where do the value of urlProfile and NameStr come from ?

Comment: From another activity. and i access to them from getStringExtra (see the edit)

Comment: theese two strings are from an activity in which i sign in google+ account. So i retrieve from that activity the name of the profile and the url of the photo profile, so i can shows them in my navigation drawer

Comment: ok, I see no reason for your code to not work. AS for retrieving you can use the code i added anywhere, as long you have a non null context object :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65722/discussion-between-dexter-and-end-game).